# Service bus + webjob in MVC. Sending string as Message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-webjobs, azureservicebus

I'm trying to learn using Service Bus with Webjob. I'm using 3 projects, one **Writer**, **Webjob**, and **Reader**. I want to send message via service bus when passing on. I'm trying to send a message from **Write**-project, pass it to **WebJob** and convert text to uppercase, and then pass it on to **Reader via queue again.**

I got all these 3 projects in same solution (using visual studio).

This is how my **WebJob**'s `function.cs` looks like:

```
namespace WebJob {
    public class Functions {

        public static void ProcessQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("test")] BrokeredMessage message, TextWriter log)
        {
            var text = message.GetBody<string>().ToUppder();

            Console.WriteLine(text);
            log.WriteLine(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Connectionstring, and other stuff on azure are settled. But I have no clue how to send text from `WriterController` in **Writer** project to **WebJob**(convert message to uppercase) and pass it on to `ReaderController` and display it in **Reader** project.

I got no code for controllers yet as I've no clue how to send it on..

How do I send message from **Writer** to **Reader** in this way?

Comment: So the writer send a message to the webjob using a queue then the webjob receive the message, convert the message and send the new message to another queue and then the reader read message sent by the webjob ?

Comment: Did you have a look at how to send a message to a queue ? it is pretty straigth forward

Comment: @Thomas I'm able to send to queue from a Console application and read from another Console application(but without webjob included) by following this [example](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues/). But the I couldn't not make it work via MVC controller. I could hardly find any MVC example.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm using 3 projects, one Writer, Webjob, and Reader. I want to send message via service bus when passing on. I'm trying to send a message from Write-project, pass it to WebJob and convert text to uppercase, and then pass it on to Reader via queue again.

It seems that you’d like to create Service Bus queue messages from ‘Write’ project, and then a WebJob that could be triggered by Service Bus will convert message content to uppercase and insert the message to Azure storage queue, and then ‘Read’ project will display the message from Azure storage queue. If that is the case, you could refer to the following steps and code to design your project.

In your **WriterController** action method, you could create Service Bus queue messages.

```
var connectionString = "yourconnectionstring";
var queueName = "yourqueuename";

var client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, queueName);

string mes = "your queue message";
var message = new BrokeredMessage(mes);

client.Send(message);

//redirect to another page to display message
//Thread.Sleep(2000);

//return Redirect("http://xxxx/{YourReaderControllerName}/ReadMessage");
```

In your **WebJob** function, you could convert the Service Bus queue message to uppercase and insert it as an Azure storage queue message while processing a Service Bus queue message.

```
public static void CreateQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("servicebusqueuename")] string message, [Queue("azurestoragequeuename")] out string outputQueueMessage, TextWriter log)
{
    var text = message.ToUpper();

    outputQueueMessage = text;

    log.WriteLine(message);

}
```

In your **ReaderController** action method, you could get message from Azure storage queue.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
                        CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();
CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("azurestoragequeuename ");
CloudQueueMessage retrievedMessage = queue.GetMessage();

string qmes = retrievedMessage.AsString;

//Process the message, and then delete the message
//queue.DeleteMessage(retrievedMessage);
```

edit:

> Is it possible to send via another Service Bus queue2 from WebJob to WriterController instead? If so, would you mind modify it from Storage queue to Service Bus queue ?

You could refer to this code snippet to create a new message in another Service Bus queue named " queue2" when WebJob process a Service Bus queue message.

```
public static void CreateQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue")] string message, [ServiceBus("queue2")] out string outputQueueMessage)
{
    outputQueueMessage = message.ToUpper();

    //Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, I was too lazy to write all this code :-)

Comment: Thanks I'm able to send message, but I can't receive the message in `WriterController` as I'm getting null error "`Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: connectionString" at ConnectionString in `ReaderController``. I've [`DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=MyProjectName;AccountKey=MyKey1Here=="`](https://www.connectionstrings.com/windows-azure/). However I'm not sure about Storage queue yet. Is it possible to send via another Service Bus `queue2` from `WebJob` to `WriterController` instead? If so, would you mind modify it from Storage  queue to Service Bus `queue` ?

Comment: @Ezony I edit the reply and share you the code snippet, you could refer to it.